# How can I specify the qubits on quantum computers that I want to use?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, simulation

Suppose I have the following 2-qubit quantum circuit:

```
qrz = QuantumRegister(2,'q')
crz = ClassicalRegister(3,'c')
qc = QuantumCircuit(qrz,crz)
qc.rx(np.pi/3,0)
qc.cry(np.pi/2,0,1)
```

I want to run this circuit on a real quantum computer, depending on the real-time error rate, I might want to use different qubits on the hardware. For example, suppose here's the calibration data of my `backend`:

[image]

Is there a way I can specify that I want to use qubit 4 and 5 on this quantum computer? I tried to generate a quantum circuit with 6 qubits and append my quantum circuit to qubit 4 and 5, then run the entire circuit on that quantum computer. Is there a simpler way I can do that without generating another large circuit? Thanks!

Comment: Same questions here, every time using ibmq I have to create a circuit with number of qubits equal number of qubits in the ibmq machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `initial_layout` method?

For instance,

```
from qiskit import IBMQ, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.x(1)
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend= provider.get_backend('ibmq_santiago'),
                                   shots = 8192,
                                   initial_layout = [3,4],
                                   optimization_level = 3)
results = quantum_instance.execute(circuit)
```

If you go and look at the circuit that being executed, you will see that it uses qubit 3 and 4 of the device:

[image]

---

If you don't to use `quantum_instance` but instead you want to use `execute` class directly, then you can  just specify the `initial_layout` method in `execute`. For example:

```
result = execute(circuit, backend=provider.get_backend('ibmq_santiago'),
 initial_layout = [3,4], shots= 1000)
```

This will also make sure qubit 3 and 4 of the hardware are use when you execute your circuit.

Answer (score 2):

> ... depending on the real-time error rate, I might want to use different qubits on the hardware.

Qiskit provides a transpiler pass that chooses a noise-adaptive layout based on current calibration data for the backend; [`NoiseAdaptiveLayout`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.transpiler.passes.NoiseAdaptiveLayout.html).

To use it, first transpile your circuit with the parameter `layout_method` equals `"noise_adaptive"`

```
transpiled_circuit = transpile(qc, backend = chosen_backend, layout_method = "noise_adaptive")
```

Then execute the transpiled circuit:

```
qobj = assemble(transpiled_circuit)
chosen_backend.run(qobj)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's really helpful. I just tried that method on `ibmq_casablanca`. However, the calibration data shows that qubit 4 and 5 as well as their connection has the lowest error rate, but the system picked qubit 5 and 6 for me. Is that more noise adaptive?

Comment: I'm just providing a general answer to the question I quoted at the beginning. For simple circuits, like the one in your question, may be the best option you have is to follow @KAJ226 suggestion.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!