# Parallel calculation of expectation values of operator for different quantum states qiskit on a QPU

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I need to calculate the expectation values of an operator `h` for various quantum states `ψ` on an IBMQ quantum machine. This can be done using the method described in [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12210) answer like the following,

```
 for i, inp in enumerate(x):
     parameters = {list(a.parameters)[0]: inp}
     ψ = CircuitStateFn(a.assign_parameters(parameters))
     measurable_expression = StateFn(h, is_measurement=True).compose(ψ)   
     expectation = PauliExpectation().convert(measurable_expression)
     sampler = CircuitSampler(qi).convert(expectation)
     y[i] = sampler.eval().real 
     z[i] = sampler.eval().imag
```

Now, I've noticed that these jobs sits idle in the queue for a long time before being executed which itself doesn't take too long. So I am thinking of submitting multiple jobs in parallel. I thought of [providing](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/parallel.html) a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to the backend but it seems that it only works with `AerSimulator` not real quantum hardware.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all the measurement expressions in one [list operator](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.list_ops.ListOp.html). This way, all the circuits needed to be executed will be sent to the backend at once as a single job:

```
from qiskit.opflow.list_ops import ListOp

measurable_expressions_list = []
for i, inp in enumerate(x):
    parameters = {list(a.parameters)[0]: inp}
    ψ = CircuitStateFn(a.assign_parameters(parameters))
    measurable_expression = StateFn(h, is_measurement=True).compose(ψ)
    measurable_expressions_list.append(measurable_expression)

expect_ops = PauliExpectation().convert(ListOp(measurable_expressions_list))
sampler = CircuitSampler(quantum_instance)
sampled_ops = sampler.convert(expect_ops)
expectation_values = sampled_ops.eval()

for i, exp_val in enumerate(expectation_values):
    y[i] = exp_val.real
    z[i] = exp_val.imag

print(y, z)
```

Comment: Does this split your circuits into multiple jobs, submit them, and consolidate the results if the number of circuits exceed the maximum allowed for a backend per job like `IBMQJobManager.run` does? https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12758

Comment: Yes! This happens in [`run_circuits()`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/main/qiskit/utils/run_circuits.py) function which is used by `QuantumInstance` class.

Comment: Is it possible to map the virtual qubits to particular physical qubits (something that I can do if I have access to the circuit) in the method above? For example https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17736/how-can-i-specify-the-qubits-on-quantum-computers-that-i-want-to-use

Comment: Note that, `CircuitSampler` takes an instance of `QuantumInstance` as a parameter (`qi` in your code snippet). Which means you can use the exact same idea.

Comment: I specifically want to use `NoiseAdaptiveLayout`. Do you think this will do the trick?
`noise_adaptive_layout = NoiseAdaptiveLayout(backend.properties())
pass_manager = PassManager()
pass_manager.append(noise_adaptive_layout)
qi = QuantumInstance(backend, pass_manager=pass_manager, seed_transpiler=seed,  seed_simulator=seed, noise_model=noise_model)`

Comment: That leads to the error `Error is : The Qobj uses gates (['h', 'sdg', 'rx']) that are not among the basis gates (['id', 'rz', 'sx', 'x', 'cx', 'reset']). Error code: 1106.. Re-submit the circuits.`

Comment: Instead of creating a new pass manager and struggling with its configuration, you can use one of the preset pass managers and change its `layout_method`:
`pmc = PassManagerConfig.from_backend(backend)`
`pmc.layout_method = 'noise_adaptive'`
`pass_manager = level_2_pass_manager(pmc)`

Comment: Thanks. Any specific reason why you have `level_2_pass_manager` there instead of say `level_3_pass_manager`? I tried using the later in the above code which leads to `TypeError: TwoQubitWeylDecomposition.__new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'unitary_matrix'`